# Access denied for .net AWS SDK when trying to list buckets

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got the problem that I am trying to simply list buckets with .net C# SDK for AWS S3 but I always get an Access Denied Exception. I work on Windows 10.

Error Message is: `Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: 'Access Denied'`

My C# code is:

```
namespace AwsEmptyApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client();

            ListBucketsResponse response = client.ListBuckets();
            foreach (S3Bucket b in response.Buckets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", b.BucketName, b.CreationDate);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set the proxy manually with:

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.RegionEndpoint = //ENDPOINT
config.ProxyHost = //Proxy http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT
```

Or:

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.RegionEndpoint = //ENDPOINT
config.ProxyHost = //Proxy http://PROXYIP:PROXYPORT 
config.ProxyPort = 8080;
config.ProxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw);
```

The curious thing is that it is working with the local CLI.
`aws s3api head-bucket --bucket [BUCKETNAME]` is working.
`aws s3 ls [BUCKET]` is working is well. 
I can see all the data in the webinterface as well.

I checked my role with `aws sts get-caller-identity` and my credentials with `aws configure list` and everything is okay.

I am working behind a proxy. The proxy settings are set in my user and system variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` in the format `http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT` .

My AWS credentials are stored in `C:\Users\[User]\.aws\credentials`

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Solved it :)

I had a local `app.config` file where I have to declare which profile from the credentials file to use and the region with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="name"/>
        <add key="AWSRegion" value="region" />
    </appSettings>
  <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Then I've added the `role_arn=` in the credentials file and it worked (just had to install `AWSSDK.SecurityToken` in NugGet because that was missing as well)